# Foreach loop not working in android for custom object

Tags: android-listview, foreach, count, iteration

I am trying to store the count of number of times an item from a list view is clicked  in a custom array list but in my code the quantity of only the first clicked item is increasing and if i click on any other item then it gets added to the list view instead of increasing the quantity. Please tell me if you know any other method to get the count. Thanks

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           Flowers item = (Flowers) parent.getAdapter().getItem(position);
           if(item == null)
           {
               Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"item is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }else {

                    selectedItems items = new selectedItems();
                    items.setName(item.getName());
                    items.setCategory(item.getCategory());
                    Counter counter = new Counter();
                    if(selectedItemsArrayList.isEmpty())
                    {

                        counter.CartItemPosition = 0;
                        counter.MenuItemPosition = position;
                        counter.quantity = 1;
                        items.setQuantity(counter.quantity);
                        count.add(counter);
                        selectedItemsArrayList.add(items);

                    }
               else
                    {
                        for(Counter c : count)
                        {
                            if(c.MenuItemPosition == position)
                            {
                                c.quantity = c.quantity + 1;
                                int i = c.CartItemPosition;
                                selectedItemsArrayList.get(i).setQuantity(c.quantity);
                                break;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Counter obj = new Counter();
                                obj.MenuItemPosition = position;
                                obj.CartItemPosition++;
                                obj.quantity=1;
                                count.add(obj);
                                items.setQuantity(obj.quantity);
                                selectedItemsArrayList.add(items);
                                return;
                            }

                        }

                    }


               }
       }
   });
```

and my Counter class is

```
public class Counter {
  public int CartItemPosition;
  public int MenuItemPosition;
  public int quantity;}
```

Comment: You are defining the selectedItemList every time with `selectedItems items = new selectedItems();` so your list resets and you have basically none selected.  You have to define the selectedItems somewhere else preferably in the constructor so that you don't clear it on every item click

Comment: I want to create a object only when the user clicks the listview item that's why I am defining it inside the onclick block. I have a found a solution to get the count, if I take the code which is inside the else block outside the for loop it works fine but I am wondering if there is any other way of doing it more efficiently